# Binary_classification_using_BERT_Pytorch : Key error

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to modify a network on MultiLabel Classification to Binary Classification using the Pytorch library and BERT model from Hugging Face. I am getting a 'Key error' while training. I am trying to debug but no luck so far.

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 2047

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1998/2908429342.py in <module>
     78 LR = 1e-6
     79 
---> 80 train(model, df_train, df_val, LR, EPOCHS)

/tmp/ipykernel_1998/2908429342.py in train(model, train_data, val_data, learning_rate, epochs)
     25             total_loss_train = 0
     26 
---> 27             for train_input, train_label in train_dataloader:
     28 
     29 #                 train_label = train_label.to(device)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    528             if self._sampler_iter is None:
    529                 self._reset()
--> 530             data = self._next_data()
    531             self._num_yielded += 1
    532             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    568     def _next_data(self):
    569         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 570         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    571         if self._pin_memory:
    572             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     47     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     48         if self.auto_collation:
---> 49             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     50         else:
     51             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     47     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     48         if self.auto_collation:
---> 49             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     50         else:
     51             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

/tmp/ipykernel_1998/3019722733.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
     21 
     22         batch_texts = self.get_batch_texts(idx)
---> 23         batch_y = self.get_batch_labels(idx)
     24 
     25         return batch_texts, batch_y

/tmp/ipykernel_1998/3019722733.py in get_batch_labels(self, idx)
     13 
     14     def get_batch_labels(self, idx):
---> 15         return np.array(self.labels[idx])
     16 
     17     def get_batch_texts(self, idx):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    940 
    941         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 942             return self._get_value(key)
    943 
    944         if is_hashable(key):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1049 
   1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
   1053 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 2047
```

**Here is the dataset class:**

```
class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, df):

        self.labels = df['target']
        self.texts = [tokenizer(text, padding='max_length', max_length = 512, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt") for text in df['text']]

    def classes(self):
        return self.labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

    def get_batch_labels(self, idx):
        return np.array(self.labels[idx])

    def get_batch_texts(self, idx):
        return self.texts[idx]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):

        batch_texts = self.get_batch_texts(idx)
        batch_y = self.get_batch_labels(idx)

        return batch_texts, batch_y
```

**And here are the model and training loop:**

```
from torch import nn
from transformers import BertModel

class BertClassifier(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, dropout=0.5):

        super(BertClassifier, self).__init__()

        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(768, 1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, input_id, mask):

        _, pooled_output = self.bert(input_ids= input_id, attention_mask=mask,return_dict=False)
        dropout_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        linear_output = self.linear(dropout_output)
        final_layer = self.sigmoid(linear_output)

        return final_layer
```

```
from torch.optim import Adam
from tqdm import tqdm

def train(model, train_data, val_data, learning_rate, epochs):

    train, val = Dataset(train_data), Dataset(val_data)

    train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)
    val_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val, batch_size=2)

    use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
    device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr= learning_rate)

#     if use_cuda:

#             model = model.cuda()
#             criterion = criterion.cuda()

    for epoch_num in range(epochs):

            total_acc_train = 0
            total_loss_train = 0

            for train_input, train_label in tqdm(train_dataloader):

#                 train_label = train_label.to(device)
                mask = train_input['attention_mask']
                input_id = train_input['input_ids'].squeeze(1)

                output = model(input_id, mask)
                
                train_label = (train_label.unsqueeze(1))
                print(output)
                print(train_label)
                
                batch_loss = criterion(output, train_label.float())
                total_loss_train += batch_loss.item()
                
                acc = (output.argmax(dim=1) == train_label).sum().item()
                total_acc_train += acc

                model.zero_grad()
                batch_loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
            
            total_acc_val = 0
            total_loss_val = 0

            with torch.no_grad():

                for val_input, val_label in tqdm(val_dataloader):

                    val_label = val_label.to(device)
                    mask = val_input['attention_mask']
                    input_id = val_input['input_ids'].squeeze(1)

                    output = model(input_id, mask)
                    
                    val_label = val_label.unsqueeze(1)
                    
                    batch_loss = criterion(output, val_label.float())
                    total_loss_val += batch_loss.item()
                    
                    acc = (output.argmax(dim=1) == val_label).sum().item()
                    total_acc_val += acc
            
            print(
                f'Epochs: {epoch_num + 1} | Train Loss: {total_loss_train / len(train_data): .3f} \
                | Train Accuracy: {total_acc_train / len(train_data): .3f} \
                | Val Loss: {total_loss_val / len(val_data): .3f} \
                | Val Accuracy: {total_acc_val / len(val_data): .3f}')
                  
EPOCHS = 5
model = BertClassifier()
LR = 1e-6
              
train(model, df_train, df_val, LR, EPOCHS)
```

I have tried both using sigmoid at the final layer with CrossEntropyLoss and without sigmoid with BCEloss. Pardon me if it's any blunderous mistake as I am a beginner and don't have good experience! :)

Comment: You're using a tokenizer in your `Dataset` class. What is it/where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

This KeyError is caused by your dataframe.The index of your dataframe is not continuously.You should add `df.reset_index(drop=True)` before instantiating Dataset or add `.to_list()` in `Dataset.__init__` like `self.labels = df['target'].to_list()`.

Comment: Yup you were right! Thanks for help! :)